# Can't remove product image because "This is a required field."

Tags: magento-1.9, product, admin, product-images, products-management

How can I remove those product images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not very precise but the message has most likely nothing to do with the image you try to delete. If you try to save a product with a missing required attribute, for example after you made it required, you will get this message, no matter what you change.

Pay attention to the warning icons on the left tabs to find the missing values.

Comment: Yes you have always to enter a label to delete an image. I don't know when they implement this.